# I would like for the Login page in my React application to redirect to a specific path if the user is already logged in

Tags: reactjs

I've already tried conditional rendering on my Login page but it appears that every time I manually change the url to localhost/login, my redux state gets blown away and isAuthenticated is set to false.

Here's what my App.js file looks like:

```js
const App = (props) => {
    const {
      authenticated
    } = props;
    console.log("From app, authenticated: ", authenticated);
    return ( <
      Router >
      <
      Switch >
      <
      Route exact path = "/register"
      component = {
        Register
      }
      /> <
      Route exact path = "/login"
      render = {
        (props) => < Login { ...props
        }
        authenticated = {
          authenticated
        }
        />} / >
        <
        PrivateRoute
        authenticated = {
          authenticated
        }
        exact
        path = "/showcase"
        component = {
          Application
        }
        /> < /
        Switch > <
        /Router>
      );
    };

    const Login = (props) => {
      const {
        loginUser,
        authenticated,
        history
      } = props;
      if (!authenticated) {
        return ( <
          Paper className = "Paper"
          elevation = {
            3
          } >
          ...
          <
          /Paper>
        );
      } else return <Redirect to = "/showcase" / > ;
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When you manually set the url, are you assigning the value directly to window.location.href? If so, this triggers a full page reload, resetting props to defaults. If you are preserving login state using local/sessionStorage, you just need to make sure to populate your store/props from this stored state each time your app is mounted.

Comment: Thank you Brian.  I am manually setting URL in the browser window.  What you say makes sense; however, my challenge is that my token is stored in an http only cookie upon successful authentication and I store a status of isAuthenticated set to true in a redux store.  One idea is to store something in local storage (not the JWT) that preserves my logged in status but not sure if this is a best practice.

Comment: Problem solved.  I used the useEffect hook in my App component to check login status on the server and updated the isAuthenticated flag accordingly in the app's redux store.  Thank you Brian!!